# Porque pasa esto a la hora de ordenar chars en Java?

Tags: java, ordenamiento

tengo una duda con respecto a Java, estoy aprendiendo ordenamiento de vectores y al ejecutar el siguiente código (ordenamiento burbuja) me surge algo que no entiendo. Aplicando el código con numeros me devuelve el resultado de mayor a menor(hasta ahí entiendo)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int array [] = {2,5,1,5,7,1};
    for (int i=0; i < array.length-1; i++){
        for (int j=i+1; j < array.length; j++){
            if (array[i] < array[j]){
                int aux = array[j];
                array[j] = array[i];
                array[i] = aux;

            }
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++){
        System.out.print(array[k]+" ");
    }
    }

//VECTOR ORDENADO: 7 5 5 2 1 1
```

Sin embargo a la hora de ordenar chars alfabéticamente con el mismo código, me da como resultado desde menor a mayor

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        char array [] = {'d','b','a','j','w','z'};
        for (int i=0; i < array.length-1; i++){
            for (int j=i+1; j < array.length; j++){
                if (array[i] < array[j]){
                    char aux = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[i];
                    array[i] = aux;
    
                }
            }
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++){
            System.out.print(array[k]+" ");
        }
        }

//VECTOR ORDENADO: z w j d b a
```

A que se debe esto?
Se supone que debería ir la letra "a" primero

Comment: Cuando comparas entre caracteres, internamente estas comprando sus códigos ascii por lo tanto tu código esta ordenando según su codigo ascii de cada char, y como tu primer ejemplo con números esta ordenando descendentemente tambien lo hara tu vector de chars también esta ordenando descendentemente.

Comment: Veo la matrix... Gracias @Spider-Man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cuando hace la comparación `if(array[i] < array[j])` lo que realmente esta haciendo es comparando el valor numérico de cada `char`.[image: representación numérica de cada carácter]

como puede ver el valor numérico decimal de "z" es 122. mientras que el valor numérico de "w" es 119. por lo que al ordenarlo de manera descendente empieza por z(122) luego w(119) y así hasta terminar con los valores del arreglo.

Comment: Wow!, nunca lo pensé así, muchas gracias